# Preventing symbol rotation of point character symbols combined with line features in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, symbology, line, markers

I have a line feature that needs to have a marker symbol at set distances along it. I want the markers to NOT rotate with the line orientation but can not find out how.
I am working with arcmap 10,4

I created a new marker symbol in style manager like this.
[image]

I then used symbol property editor to create a line symbol with a dashed line and marker line and marker line symbol.

This is the result I get. But I need the R labels to always be rotated to the same angle and correctly orientated to the data frame.

[image]

Comment: Flip 'bad' lines?

Comment: Thank you for your input but unfortunately that will not work. This is only a small sample there are a lot more lines with all sorts of orientations and curve. The letters need to be facing the same way despite the line orientation.

Comment: The line in the example is also not in two parts, it is one continua line and I do not know why the labels rotate all of a sudden.

Comment: It might look like one line, bit most likely it is not. Select it in editing session and explode, using advanced editing toolset.

Comment: Thank you for the help FelixIP. That did fix the problem of the complacently rotated letters (uppdated image in the question). But this does not change the fact the letters are orientated the same way as the line and not square to the data frame. Do you know of any method of giving them a fixed orientation that is constant for each point.

Comment: Finally you defined 'correct' orientation. To do so you need to generate points on the line and label them, not line. You can use linear referencing for point generation. Alternatively search my answers, I remember posting a script for placing points at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be an option in ArcMap but this is an option in ArcGIS Pro. There is an option there to choose placement properties of marker lines.

[image]